# QSerialPort crashing when run outside of dev enviornment

Tags: c++, qt

I have a fairly simple program that runs, find all the serial ports connected to the computer, and prints them onto a GUI screen.  Right now, this code works fine when running inside Qt Creator, but once I try to take the executable and place it with the dll's to run as a standalone program, I am crashing.  I am running Qt 5.3 with MSVC2013, 32bit.  The computer is running windows 7 32bit.

here is a sample of the code that I am running:

```
void ApplicationWindow::findComPorts(){
    qDebug() << "find com ports selected";
    QString comText;
    QString messageText = "locating com ports";
    int i = 0;
    comText = "Locating Com Ports:";
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setText(messageText);
    msg.exec();
    foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()){
        i++;
        messageText = "locating com port " + QString::number(i);
        msg.setText(messageText);
        msg.exec();

        comText = comText + "\nName: ";
        comText = comText + info.portName();
        comText = comText + "\nDescription: ";
        comText = comText + info.description;
        comText = comText + "\nManufacturer: ";
        comText = comText + info.manufacturer();
        comText = comText + "\n";

        messageText = "Com port " + QString::number(i);
        messageText = messageText + " located";
        msg.setText(messageText);
        msg.exec();
    }
    messageText = "All com ports located";
    msg.setText(messageText);
    msg.exec();
    locatedComPorts->setText(comText); //locatedComPorts is type QLabel
    //and is declared in the header and is a label on the main GUI box
}
```

When running inside the debugger, the above lines has the following output:

inside debugger:

```
find com ports selected
```

popups (currently single com port connected to computer):

```
locating com ports

locating com port 1

Com port 1 located

All com ports located
```

when the program is running independantly, I get the following popups:

```
locating com ports

locating com port 1

Com port 1 located
```

at which point the program crashes to the desktop.

Current DLL's bundled with the program include:

icudt51.dll, icuin51.dll, icuuc51.dll, libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll, msvcp120.dll, msvcr120.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5SerialPort.dll, and Qt5Widgets.dll

additionally, there is a subfolder called "platforms" which contains qwindows.dll

I don't think that there are any dll's missing that could be causing this issue, and I am not certain what else could be causing it.  The only code that I have changed since I encountered this issue is adding the message box so that way I can identify where the program is crashing when not using the debugger, so it was crashing before the qmessagebox was added.  Does anyone know what might be causing this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone stumbles across a similar problem, I was successfully able to fix it by modifying the foreach loop to pull the declarations out of the for statement, changing the list to be a pointer to QSerialPortInfo::AvailablePorts() instead of using that list directly, and deleting info at the end of the function.  Below is an example of the code which functions correctly, which can be swapped in the code posted in the question.

```
...
QSerialPortInfo* info = new QSerialPortInfo;
QList<QSerialPortInfo> * PortList = new QList<QSerialPortInfo>;
*PortList = QSerialPortInfo::AvailablePorts();
foreach(*info, *PortList){
    ...
}
...
delete info;
```

Comment: The same problem occurred at VS2019 32bit Qt5.15; when setting the lib mode to "/MTd";

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple and stable code:

```
QSerialPortInfo sinfo;
QList<QSerialPortInfo> slist = sinfo.availablePorts();

for(int i=0; i<slist.size(); i++)
{
    QString name = slist[i].portName();
    QSerialPort sp(name);
    if( sp.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {
        sp.close();
        ui.comboBoxPort->addItem(name);
    }
}
```